# Vue computed setter with object prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

The idea is to pass different objects to an input component, have them displayed there as CSV and be able to edit/validate the text and change the style depending on the validation results. Here is the code I currently have:

```html
<div id="vue">
    <base-input :cslice="c.workspace"></base-input>
</div>
```

javascript:

```js
(function () {

  Vue.component('base-input', {
    props: ['cslice'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        colors: ['red', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'],
        ind: 1
      }
    },
    computed: {
      str: {
        get: function () {
          return Object.values(this.cslice).join(", ");
        },
        set: function (val) {
          if(val.indexOf('0'))
            this.ind = Math.floor(this.colors.length * Math.random());
        },
      },
      styleObj: {
        get: function () {
          return { color: this.colors[this.ind] };
        },
        set: function () {

        },
      }
    },
    template: '<div><input v-model="str" :style="styleObj" type="text"/></div>'
  });

  let vue = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: {
      c: {},
    },
    created: function () {
      this.c = Object.assign({}, this.c, {
        workspace: { width: 820, height: 440 },
      });
    },

  });

})();
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tfoller/sz946qe2/3/

This code allows me to delete the last character only if the new style is the same as the current, otherwise the text is practically uneditable, how do I fix this problem so I'm able to normally edit the input field?

Comment: I would simplify this question and ask it again.  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) regarding minimal.  If you can, make a contrived example that only shows the unknown subject matter

Comment: Unfortunately, this is minimal. For example, if I don't change the style of this component along with using a complex parsing function then its behaviour is different and I can not represent my problem.

Comment: You would use completely different objects.  Surely the same question can be shown with a different, simpler app that doesn't do what this one does

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to show somewhat related different simpler example

Answer (score 1):

Since the computed in the child uses a prop in its getter, you need to `$emit` back up a value with the same shape in its setter:

```js
set: function (val) {
   const arrValues = val.split(',').map(v => v.trim());
   console.log(arrValues);
   this.$emit('input', {
      width: arrValues[0],
      height: arrValues[1]
   })
},
```

That means reversing some of the string formatting stuff you were doing in order to get the right shape.

Listen for that `input` event in the parent.  You can change your prop name to `value` so that you can use `v-model` as the listener:

```html
<base-input v-model="c.workspace"></base-input>
```

Move all of the color changing functionality into a separate method in the child that's triggered by changing the input as well.  Here's a demo:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/p25wLcqr/)